# Fill the column with right formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I can't find an easy solution to my problem. I have a column with 10k+ values and I need to copy the value to definite one then continue copying it

Please look at the picture below! Yellow color is just end of column. Left values (column C) what I have, right (column E) - what I want to get

I can't figure out if there is efficient way to do it. I tried using "IF(IsEmpty..." statement.

[image]

Comment: Hi, your question is needlessly confusing. Can you please be more precise? What does this (" Left values (column C) what I have, right (column E) - what I want to get.") mean?

Comment: Scott Craner gave me perfect solution! Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In E3:

```
=IF(C3<>"",C3,E2)
```

Then copy down as far as you want results.

[image]

Comment: Actually, I want to think like you! :) Easy solution for me. Thank you!